# What is wrong with my question! [Reverse Direction of Merging]

Tags: discussion, support, merging

My question: [How to filter any part of description or option from manpage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159214/66803) is merged with **Newer** question: [Is there way to see `man` document only for specified option of a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180639/66803).

The newer question should be merged as duplicate but here things are opposite! As you can see that [my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159214/66803) posted on *Oct 4 '14 at 5:45* and the [newer question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180639/66803) posted on *Jan 23'15 at 13:57*.

In-spite of this, My question is merged with newer question! (and reasoned exact duplicate!)

Comment: Related: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/reverse-duplicate-direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your question! Why would you think anything was wrong with it? Merging is done to improve the site,  it should not be perceived as an attack.

Which question is older and which newer has nothing to do with it.  In this particular case,  the new question had more and better answers.  I therefore chose to merge in this way since that would cause the least disruption.

Since the two questions were basically identical,  merging makes a lot of sense and doing it in this way moves the smallest number of posts around.

Comment: [OK](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/260388)